# Mac OS X - Adding and Removing Items From an NSOutlineView With Core Data

Tags: macos, core-data, swift2, xcode7

I want to add and remove items from an NSOutlineView and animate the changing view. In my OutlineViewController scene I have a NSTreeController bound to my Core Data Entity and my ManagedObjectContext. My NSOutlineView's Content and Selection properties are bound to my NSTreeController and the NSOutlineView > Table Cell View > Model Key Path is bound to the associated objectValue.*propertyName*.

Assume there is an 'Add' button. I am currently calling the NSTreeController's 'insertChild' method and pass in the Entity name. This works exactly as I want except there is no animation. Similar for the TreeController's removeObjectAtArrangedObjectIndexPath method.

I see that the NSOutlineView provides a insertItemsAtIndexes:inParent:withAnimation: method which would provide the animation but I'm unsure if this will liaise with Core Data and insert a new Entity into the model and I'm not sure how to use this to insert a new item as a child of the selected item?

Any advise very welcome.

Comment: You could start with trying the same trick as animating a tableview with bindings. [Using NSTableView Animations with Bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541613/using-nstableview-animations-with-bindings)